# Add IP addresses to systemd-network besides netplan

Tags: linux-networking, ip, systemd, netplan, systemd-networkd

On an Ubuntu 20.04 server, netplan is used to configure the network. It can configure ordinary static IP addresses but I need additional IPv6 addresses with preferred_lft=0. Netplan can't do that (there's an open bug for that). So I found out that it actually goes like this:

- Netplan reads its own limited config and transforms it into a config for the more powerful systemd-network.
- systemd-network probably passes on its data to things like the `ip` command when a network device appears.
- The network device then applies the actual configuration. Down here everything is possible.

If netplan can't help me, I tried to move on to systemd. Since I don't want to remove the apparently widely used and highly praised netplan entirely, I just need to add my additional addresses besides the basic netplan config.

I tried to create the file /etc/systemd/network/web-ipv6.conf with this content:

```
[Match]
Name=ens33 (this is the name from the existing netplan file)

[Address]
Address=fd9e:21a7:a92c:2323::2/64
PreferredLifetime=0
```

The address fd9e:21a7:a92c:2323::1 is configured statically via netplan. In this demo it's a local address, in reality it's my server's main IPv6 address. Additional addresses have a different interface value, like this ...::2.

I guess I have to apply my config with `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` but I'm not sure. The log says things I'd consider a success. But the new IPv6 address ...::2 doesn't show up in `ip addr`.

In the man page for systemd.network I've read that only a single file for a `[Match]` will be used. I clearly have two files now: one from netplan (/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-ens33.network) and my other one. So this doesn't seem to work. But I don't want to edit netplan's file as it will surely be overwritten sometime.

How should I continue with this? I'd like to have a separate and persistent file that only adds my additional addresses. I'm going to manage that file in a custom script.

Should I go back to `ifupdown` or what it was in the old days? In a previous server setup I use a file named /etc/network/if-up.d/dynamic6 that contains all the `ip addr add ... dev ... preferred_lft 0` commands. From what I've seen this is today considered deprecated.

Comment: Is your NIC actually named ens33? If not, then it won't match. As for netplan, I prefer to dump it and configure networking directly.

Comment: Yes, the name is correct. `ip link` shows that. (That dev system is a VMware guest machine if that's interesting.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems the old ifupdown functionality has been recreated for systemd-networkd. The package **networkd-dispatcher**, pre-installed on Ubuntu Server 20.04, lets me add a script to /etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/ that is executed when a device comes up. In that script I can run `ip addr add` commands as I need. It is called on `netplan apply`, `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` and on system boot. In all cases, my additional IPv6 addresses were added as "deprecated" when they'd otherwise be missing.

Here's an article that explains it, with a short sample script: https://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/963-if-up-and-if-down-scripts-with-systemd.html